# Spark dataframe not adding columns with null values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a new column by adding two existing columns in my dataframe.

Original dataframe

```
╔══════╦══════╗
║ cola ║ colb ║
╠══════╬══════╣
║ 1    ║ 1    ║
║ null ║ 3    ║
║ 2    ║ null ║
║ 4    ║ 2    ║
╚══════╩══════╝
```

Expected output with derived column

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ cola ║ colb ║ colc ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ 1    ║ 1    ║    2 ║
║ null ║ 3    ║    3 ║
║ 2    ║ null ║    2 ║
║ 4    ║ 2    ║    6 ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

When I use df = df.withColumn('colc',df.cola+df.colb), it doesn't add columns with null values.

The output I get is:

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ cola ║ colb ║ colc ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ 1    ║ 1    ║ 2    ║
║ null ║ 3    ║ null ║
║ 2    ║ null ║ null ║
║ 4    ║ 2    ║ 6    ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Is there any way to incorporate the null values into the calculation. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can **coalesce** to 0 to get a sum.
For cases where both columns are null, you can make use of conditional functions.

For your case, the code should look something like

```
df.selectExpr('*', 'if(isnull(cola) and isnull(colb), null, coalesce(cola, 0) + coalesce(colb, 0)) as colc')
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace `null` with `0` using `coalesce` function and then add the two columns together; With `selectExpr` and sql syntax:

```
df.selectExpr('*', 'coalesce(cola, 0) + coalesce(colb, 0) as colc')
```

Comment: This adds an output of 0 when adding 2 nulls together, ex. null+null = 0. Is there a way to make the output null instead, ex. null+null = null

Comment: Add a condition with `case when`: `df.selectExpr('*', 'case when cola is null and colb is null then null else coalesce(cola, 0) + coalesce(colb, 0) end as colc')`

Comment: I have a column_list and want to perform the same operation. How to do that?