# Calculate weighted average of dataframe rows with missing values

Tags: python

I have a similar situation to the one described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67433044/pyspark-calculate-row-wise-weighted-average-with-null-entries). The difference is I'm not working in Pyspark, just with pandas, numpy, etc.

Could I please ask for help in how to implement this in a Pythonic way?

Right now I have the following approach, using the dataframe in the above question as an example dataset, and assuming that there are never any missing values in the first column (i.e. 'first_value' is never missing).

The dataset is thus:

```
+------+-----------+------------+-----------+
|person|first_value|second_value|third_value|
+------+-----------+------------+-----------+
|     1|        1.0|         0.5|        0.2|
|     2|        0.9|         0.6|       null|
|     3|        0.8|        null|        0.9|
|     4|        0.8|         0.7|        0.6|
+------+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

And the weight vector is `[0.3,0.4,0.3]`

My approach so far is to programme the following: loop through each row, check what situation we're in (e.g. both 'second_value' and 'third_value' are missing; only 'second_value' is missing; only 'third_value' is missing), and then adjust the weight vector accordingly before computing the weighted average.

```
for person in dataframe:
    value_2 = dataframe.loc[person,'second_value']
    value_3 = dataframe.loc[person,'third_value']

    if value_2!=value_2 and value_3!=value_3:
       weights = [weight*(1/sum([0.3]) for weight in [0.3]]
    elif value_2!=value_2 and value_3==value_3:
       weights = [weight*(1/sum([0.3,0.3]) for weight in [0.3,0.3]]
    elif value_2==value_2 and value_3!=value_3:
       weights = [weight*(1/sum([0.3,0.4]) for weight in [0.3,0.4]]
    else:
       weights = [0.3,0.4,0.3]

    wmean = np.average([value for value in list(dataframe.loc[person,['first_value','second_value','third_value']) if value==value], weights = weights)
```

(In the code above, I'm aware that the weights vector under the first 'if' statement is just equal to 1, but I thought it would be easier to have the same formula structure for all if/elif statements.)

An additional distinction vis-à-vis the above-referenced question is that I have around twenty data columns across which to calculate the weighted average, and thus many potential permutations of what is missing. Therefore, the complicated if/elif approach above will not realistically work with so many columns.

Would someone have an idea of a neat way to implement this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Take the average with fillna=0, then multiply by sum(weights)/sum(weights dot ~pd.isnull(row))

Comment: Many thanks! That was the hint I needed. I implemented it in the following way. Happy to accept your answer if you want to post it?
    `adjfactor = sum(weights) / sum(weights*~pd.isnull(df.loc[row,valuecols]))
    weights_red = [weight/adjfactor for weight in list(weights*~pd.isnull(df.loc[row,valuecols])) if weight!=0]
    wmean = np.average(list(df.loc[row,valuecols].dropna()), weights = weights_red)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing the idea in my comment above. which is simpler than I thought because the `DataFrame.sum` method seems to do `fillna=0` automatically:

```
(df*w).sum(axis=1)/(~pd.isnull(df)*w).sum(axis=1)
```

will perform this operation in a vectorized way on all rows.